# How to change Class without using DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have List of Divs as Below.I want to change the color of Heading i.e Heading1, Heading2, Heading3 when Click Me of each Div is Clicked.I have written JQuery for the same as Below

```
    <pre>
     <div>
       <div>
          <span class="Heading">Heading1</span>
          <div>Content1</div>
          <a class="ClickMe">Click Me</a>
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div>
          <div>
            <span class="Heading">Heading2 </span>
            <div>Content2</div>
               <a class="ClickMe">Click Me</a>
           </div> 
      </div>
      <div>
          <div>
            <span class="Heading">Heading3 </span>
            <div>Content3</div>
               <a class="ClickMe">Click Me</a>
           </div> 
      </div>
      <div>
           <div>
            <span class="Heading">Heading3 </span>
            <div>Content3</div>
               <a class="ClickMe">Click Me</a>
           </div> 
      </div>    

  <script>
    $('document').ready(function(){
         $(".ClickMe").click(function(){
       $(this).parent().children(0).toggleClass('red');
     });
    });
  <script>


<style>
  .red
  {
    color : red;
  }
</style>
```

1.Now when ever I click the Click Me the Red Color is applied to the whole Div.

2.Is there any other way i can apply red color to heading alone other than using DOM

Comment: It is apparent to me that you do not know what the DOM does or means.

Comment: This makes no sense "other than using the DOM".  Guess what, you can't change the DOM without using the DOM.

Comment: I Have Table which is Inside 2 divs so what i need is I need to browse the parent table and after that I want to use the class applied for that table in div to access the table CSS attributes incase i need to change that

Comment: You can also use $(".ClickMe").click(function(){ $(this).closest('.heading').toggleClass('red'); });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ClickMe").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.Heading').toggleClass('red');
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).closest('.Heading').toggleClass('red');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $(".ClickMe").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.Heading').toggleClass('red');
  });
});
```